# 'html.sty' and latex2e

Tags: linux, latex, ubuntu-10.04, package-managers

I need to install the file 'html.sty', but don't know what package it's in. I think I need to install something called latex2e, but I don't know what package has that.

Comment: This belongs on Super User, at least until the Ubuntu Stack Exchange site becomes public.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find some information about installing LaTeX at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX, although I have to wonder why you would need the file `html.sty` (a LaTeX style file) if you don't already have LaTeX installed. But anyway: probably the simplest way to install LaTeX and a lot the associated stuff you might or might not use with it, is

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

**EDIT:** According to some Google search results I just found, `html.sty` comes with the package `latex2html`. Running

```
sudo apt-get install latex2html
```

should suffice to install it.